# Console closes in fresh install of Git Bash

Tags: windows, git, bash, git-bash

I just installed the most recent Git for Windows (https://git-scm.com/download/win) using the default installation settings. I have the 64 bit 2.10.0 version of Git running on Windows 10.

When I tried using Git Bash here, the console closes immediately and it produces a mintty.exe file with the following text:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=00100407559
rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF rbx=00000000FFFFC5D0 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=03FFFFFFFFFFFFFF rsi=0000000100444E20 rdi=00000000FFFFC5CC
r8 =0000000000000001 r9 =0000000000000001 r10=0000000000000000
r11=8000000000000000 r12=0000000100445960 r13=00000000FFFFC5E0
r14=0000000600042F70 r15=0000000100445960
rbp=00000000FFFFC6C0 rsp=00000000FFFFC580
program=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe, pid 6944, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
000FFFFC6C0  00100407559 (000FFFFC6C0, 7FFB0536FF20, 00100444DC8, 00600000001)
000FFFFC6C0  00100425455 (001801980AD, 00600041880, 001800CE622, 0000000002F)
000FFFFCCC0  00180047C0F (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  0018004590C (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFFFF0  001800459A4 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
End of stack trace
```

I have tried searching for a solution but cannot find anything.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your Windows 10 or running the Git Bash in admin mode?

Comment: Yes, tried both which turned out unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2):

Try instead the portable edition:

[`PortableGit-2.10.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.10.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.10.0-64-bit.7z.exe)

See if the a `bash --login -i`  from this package works better than when it is installed.

```
vonc@gvonc MINGW64 /bin

$ git version
git version
git version 2.10.0.windows.1

$ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

If the issue persists, check your services: for instance, in [issue 768](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/768), the [Null service](http://batcmd.com/windows/7/services/null/) wasn't started.

Check its state:

```
sc query nul
```

Start it if needed:

```
sc start null
```

Comment: Tried your advice but still getting the same issue. How do I start the Null service?

Comment: @Afungus `sc start null` (as admin). First `sc query null`

Comment: @Afungus Great: you can read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by starting the Null service on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The same error also happened to me, `git bash` would work just fine but suddenly, it won't even open and even if you uninstall and reinstalling the git bash It won't work!.

- When I try to run the `git bash` instead of launching the `mysys terminal` it will create a `stackdump` file.
  But it will not help much to find the actual problem.
- What worked for me was to delete the `_minttyrc` file in the home folder of my account.
- After that git bash will work as expected.

So what is the actual problem here?
The problem is that I was trying to edit the default terminal preferences like the `font size` and the `window size` of the `mysys terminal` but sometimes this causes the `mysys terminal` to crash!.

- So removing the `_minttyrc` in the `C:\Users\{UserName}\` directory solves this issue.
  I hope someone will find this helpul.