# Android Studio Path to Git executable

Tags: windows, git, unix, android-studio

I'm developing on windows but have installed Bash for Windows (basically a Unix terminal for those who don't know about Windows 10 anniversary update). I installed git through this terminal (`sudo apt-get install git`) as opposed to downloading it as a Windows application from GitHub.

I'm now trying to integrate Git into Android Studio, and it's asking for a path to the Git executable. Because I didn't download it as a Windows application, there is no `.exe`, and instead I've tried to give the path `C:\Users\Faizan\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\bin\git` which is where the terminal tells me where Git is when I type `type git`. I didn't really expect this to work because it's not an .exe but I'm stuck on ideas from here.

How can I make this work without having to download Git for Windows? How do people who develop on Unix systems deal with this path as they don't have an executable file either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have to download Git For Windows.

Try the portable edition: [`PortableGit-2.10.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.10.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.10.0-64-bit.7z.exe)

It [comes with a bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39424490/6309), but even without opening a bash, you sttill have (in a regular Windows CMD session) 200+ Linux commands in `<yourGit2.10>\usr\bin`.

And of course, it has a `git.exe`, which is what your Android Studio needs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That's unfortunate. So you suggest I download the portable edition (and give the path to it in android studio), but carry on using Windows Bash for git, when I'm using git outside of Android Studio?

Comment: @user3186023 You don't even need Windows bash: the portable edition comes with its own bash.

Comment: @user3186023 But yes, that is the idea. `git.exe` for Android Studio, any bash you want for the rest.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. I think I'll probably just stick to the portable edition for everything (although it shouldn't matter what I use anyway). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just out of interest, if you need a .exe path, how do Unix developers deal with this when using Android Studio to develop and version control?

Comment: @user3186023 The Android Studio installation instructions (https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) comes for Windows, Mac, and Linux. The Android Studio running on a Linux platform should not, I suspect, require an exe.

Comment: Ah if they have separate instructions then that could well be. Thanks